# How to assign size of column in a mysql with laravel 7

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5

So I'm learning laravel and now I'm in the migration part, I have faced a problem whenver i try to assign a size to an `increments` it doesn't it always shows me that the size is 10 why?

Here an example when i assign a size to a string:

```
$table->string('notificationMessage', 250);
```

it works perfectly, but when i assign a size to integer it always shows me 10:

```
$table->increments('id', 250);
```

what can i do to fix that?

Comment: int has self size )) is 2,147,483,647

Comment: @BohdanPetrenko i want to change the size in laravel not the value